# $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}^+, \forall m\in \mathbb{N}, (k = 2m + 1) \implies 11|(10^k + 1)$ - Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

So, I am having trouble proving:

$$\forall k\in \mathbb{N}^+, \forall m\in \mathbb{N},  (k = 2m + 1) \implies 11|(10^k + 1)$$

(Note: "$\mathbb{N}^+$" is the set of all positive natural numbers, so  $n \geq 1$ )

[I have been trying to prove by (simple) induction; I have done setting up the appropriate predicate capturing the claim, and also finished the base case, and also written down the inductive hypothesis.]
Now, I am in the inductive step; got down this much (see below) and then got completely stuck:

> Start: 
>        \begin{align}10^{2m+2} + 1 
>                  &= 10^{2m+1+1} + 1  \\
>                  &= 10^{2m+1} \times 10^{1} + 1\\
>                  &= (11j - 1) \times 10 + 1 , [j \in \mathbb{Z}]\\
>                  &= 110j - 10 + 1\\
>                  &= \text{Now stuck!} \end{align}

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Note: Direct proof, proof by induction, contraposition, exhaustion (cases), contradiction, etc. all ideas and contributions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Do you know congruences?

Comment: You're trying to show that $10^{2m+2}+1$ is divisible by 11, but this isn't the next step. You want to show that $11|(10^{2(m+1)+1}+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is $k$ has to be an odd number.

You should instead prove that if $10^{2m+1}+1$ is divisible by $11$ then $10^{2m+3}+1$ is divisible by $11$.

\begin{align} &10^{2m+3} + 1 \\
               &      = 10^{2m+1+2} + 1  \\
                &     = 10^{2m+1} \times  10^{2} + 1\\
                 &    = (11j - 1) \times  100 + 1 , \\
                  &   = 1100j - 99 \end{align}